# a href Links are wider than they should be

Tags: css

Here is an example.

The link for the `div class="learn"` is 1014px wide. While the button is only 215px wide.

What did I do wrong?

```
    .inside {
        width: 1014px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #people .learn {
      display: block;
      background: url(http://www.domain.com/images/learn.png);
      width: 215px; height: 51px;
      margin: 30px 0 0 20px; padding: 0;
    }

  <div id="people">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="headline"><span class="bold">Best</span> Webhosting Around. Period.</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque porttitor suscipit purus, et blandit libero tempor in. Vivamus rutrum.</p>

      <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->

      <a href="#"><div class="learn"></div></a>

      <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @AndB I cannot understand your problem, you want the link to be full sized ? or could you explain properly?

Comment: I want it to be the same size as the image (div class="learn"). It extends 1014px and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div with learn class is having a block display so browser will adjust the outer `<a>`  as   as display block and occupy the available width.

Change div display as inline-block then you can see the width of `<a>` coming as 215px

here is the example code

```
<html> 
<style> 
  .inside {
        width: 1014px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #people .learn {
           display: inline-block;

      background: url(http://www.domain.com/images/learn.png);
      width: 215px; height: 51px;
      margin: 30px 0 0 20px; padding: 0;
      border:solid 1px ;
    }
 </style>
  <div id="people">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="headline"><span class="bold">Best</span> Webhosting Around. Period.</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque porttitor suscipit purus, et blandit libero tempor in. Vivamus rutrum.</p>

      <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->

      <a href="#" style="border:solid 1px red"><div class="learn">wwww</div>fddfg</a>

      <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->

    </div>
  </div>
  </html>
```

Comment: Certainly the style of a child element does not affect the style of a parent element. The reason lies elsewhere, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML4, [your markup is not Valid](http://validator.w3.org/): [`DIV` elements MUST NOT be descendent elements of `A` elements *there*](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/links.html#edef-A).  Only [in HTML5 this is Valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).  You should not rely on HTML5 being supported by a layout engine at this point.

`div` elements are [*block-level*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html) elements (per user agent stylesheet, their default is `display: block`); barring further CSS declarations, they are as wide as their [*containing block*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#x0).

The containing block here is provided by the ancestor `div` element that has the CSS class `inside` specified (`class="inside"`).  There is a CSS rule for elements with that class – `.inside` – in your stylesheet that says that those elements should have `width: 1014px`.  So the descendent `div` element is displayed as wide as the ancestor `div` element, `1014px`.

`a` elements are *inline-level* elements (per user agent stylesheet, their default is `display: inline`); barring further declarations, they have the combined dimensions of their content.  The sole content of this `a` element is said `div` element. Therefore, the parent `a` element – the link – is as wide as the child `div` element (that does not really belong there).

The `background-image` of an element [does not automatically stretch](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-background-20120724/#the-background-size) to the dimensions of the element's box, which is probably causing your confusion about the “button” represented by that background image.